# Trying to get this string to appear in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to get this string I have in JavaScript to appear in a paragraph in my HTML page by mousing over another paragraph.

```js
function showInfo()
{
    for (i = 0; i < object2; i = i + 1)
    {
        var myParagraph = "Name of Business: " + info.insurance[i].name + "\nState: " + info.insurance[i].state + "\nDiscount: " + info.insurance[i].discount + "\n" + "(" + i + 1 + "of" + object2 + ")"
    }
}

myDiscount.addEventListener("mouseover", showInfo, false);

myDiscount.addEventListener("mouseout", showInfo, false);
```

```html
<p id="discount">Show me the discounts!</p>

<p id="myP"></p>
```

Comment: What is `object2`? What is `info.insurance`?

Comment: Do you want to use a different value of `i` each time you mouse over the `discount` paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the next element of the `info.insurance` array each time you mouse over the paragraph, you shouldn't be using a `for` loop. That will do it all at once, not once for each mouseover. You need to put the counter in a global variable, and just increment it each time you call the function.

Yuo show it by assigning it to the `innerHTML` of the paragraph. You also need to use `<br>` rather than `\n` to make newlines (unless the style of the paragraph is `pre`).

```
var insurance_counter = 0;
function showInfo() {
    var myParagraph = "Name of Business: " + info.insurance[insurance_counter].name + "<br>State: " + info.insurance[insurance_counter].state + "<br>Discount: " + info.insurance[insurance_counter].discount + "<br>(" + (insurance_counter + 1) + "of" + object2 + ")";
    document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML = myParagraph;
    insurance_counter++;
    if (insurance_counter >= object2) { // wrap around when limit reached
        insurance_counter = 0;
    }
}
```